# color sequence of sections with 3 colors

Tags: php

I have this alternating sequence of red and blue for displaying the color on the background of the sections but would like red, white and blue.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{
  $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rResult3);
  $res_row_color = ($c++ % 2) ? "red" : "blue";
}
```

Comment: server side solution is what I am looking for.

Comment: What about php solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38988911/1203805? It uses html to present result, but doesn't tightly bound to it. So you may feel yourself free to modify snippet to satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Php backend solution:

```
<?php
$rows = array(
    'Nikon', 
    'Canon', 
    'Sigma', 
    'Olympus', 
    'Pentax', 
    'Panasonic', 
    'Leica', 
    'Fujifilm',
);
$colors = array(
    'red',
    'white',
    'blue',
);

$html = '<ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
    $color = $colors[$i % count($colors)]; //magic
    $html .= '
        <li style="background: ' . htmlspecialchars($color) . '">' .
            htmlspecialchars($rows[$i]) .
        '</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;
```

Solution is universal: you may add colors into `$colors` array and It would still work.

[Online demo.](http://code.runnable.com/V7P5wMwhjataFWkz/color-sequence-of-sections-with-3-colors-for-php)

## Css frontend solution:

```css
.vendors li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: red
}

.vendors li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: white
}

.vendors li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<ul class="vendors">
  <li>Nikon</li>
  <li>Canon</li>
  <li>Sigma</li>
  <li>Olympus</li>
  <li>Pentax</li>
  <li>Panasonic</li>
  <li>Leica</li>
  <li>Fujifilm</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try `nested` `Ternary` Operator

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{ 

$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rResult3);


 $res_row_color  = ($c++ %3 == 0) ? "red" : (($c++ %3 == 1)  ? "white" : "blue");

}
```

Comment: that does not result in white for second section

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way to do this IMO would be to use pure css.

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div>Red</div>
    <div>White</div>
    <div>Blue</div>
    <!-- repeat ad-infinitum -->
</div>

<style>
    #parent > div:nth-child(3n+1){background:red;}
    #parent > div:nth-child(3n+2){background:white;}
    #parent > div:nth-child(3n+3){background:blue;}
</style>
```